# How to plot counts of elements in single dataframe column over time in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have a large df that looks like this:

```
df:

date             name
2012-12-13       cat1
2014-08-07       cat2
2012-12-25       cat1
2013-05-25       cat2
2011-09-13       cat3
```

I want to count the change in cat type over time. So the ideal chart would have a line for cat 1, a line for cat 2, and a line for cat 3. The x axis would be time (I'm thinking of changing the df$date to month and year). The y axis would be counts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `geom_freqpoly` would work for you.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date))+geom_freqpoly(aes(colour=name), size=2, alpha=I(.6))
```

I generated random data based on what you provided and used the code above to plot this.

[image: example]